# Word order in sentences starting with "How"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Could you please tell me which one is correct?

1. How China's economy is being damaged?
2. How is China's economy being damaged?

Comment: #1 isn't a sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["how the data is accessed" and "how is the data accessed", which one is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/how-the-data-is-accessed-and-how-is-the-data-accessed-which-one-is-correct)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a title or a question?

If it is the title of an article or book explaining the damage to China's economy, then the first one is correct, but it doesn't have a question mark:

> How China's economy is being damaged.

If you are asking a question then it is 2:

> How is China's economy being damaged?